# How to save time only without the date using ASP.NET MVC 5 Data Annotation "DataType.Time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

My Model Class looks like this:

```
 [DataType(DataType.Time)]
 public DateTime Time {get; set;}
```

When I run it, I have a cool an HTML 5 Input Type in Time. When I save the data, the value in my database looks like this:

```
 7/11/2014 1:00AM
```

It automatically saves the current date. I just wanna have the time saved. I'm trying to create a reservation system.

Comment: Saves it where? If you mean in the database, it sounds like you've got the wrong column type...

Comment: check the answer and the reference links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you need to store that as a string. You cannot separate `Time` from `Date` using BCL (Base Class Library) of .Net. They cannot exist as independent entities.

However youcan have a workaround to save Time in a `TimeSpan` object using this [Representing Time (not date and time) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567586/representing-time-not-date-and-time-in-c-sharp)

Comment: They certainly *can* exist as independent entities. They happen not to in the BCL, but they do in databases, and do in other libraries too...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am talking about .Net.

Comment: Well again, that can be done in libraries in .NET - my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library separates them. If you mean to say "The BCL doesn't provide separate time and date types" then that's what you should have said... which is very different from what you're actually said.

Comment: @JonSkeet Seeking feedback for my answer as well :)

Comment: Well, I'd say that it doesn't really address the question, which is about *storing* the data... and if the OP is using an appropriate database, then they can use a `TIME` field. In terms of "within the C# code" I'd advocate using Noda Time, of course :)

Answer (score 3):

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
public DateTime Hour { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar question gives a series of answers you might like, **[How do I represent a time only value in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037283/how-do-i-represent-a-time-only-value-in-net)** but the

However the overriding question is what type you should set the time to in your db, and this question **[Best way to store time (hh:mm) in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538739/best-way-to-store-time-hhmm-in-a-database)** gives more

The following will give you a string representation from your DateTime, but read the other questions and answers, and you might want to save in a format other than string to make it easier to evaluate queries...

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("t");
```

Comment: And to be generally sane. It's a shame we have no idea where the OP is storing the data. If it's in SQL Server 2008+, then a `TIME` field is the most appropriate...

Answer (score 0):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}")]
public DateTime Time {get; set;}
```

will display only the time

For reference Follow :

**[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Answer (score -2):

Just change the data type as  as string in database then you can save your time.

Comment: Using a string to store date/time values in a database is a really bad idea. Databases *do* (generally) have separate date and time types, and *that's* the better solution.