# How to insert only time into the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Data type in db is `time(7)`

Model class:

```
public DateTime intime { get; set;}
public DateTime out_time { get; set;}
```

Controller:

```
 DateTime newintime = DateTime.Parse(Request["intime"]);

 DateTime newouttime = DateTime.Parse(Request["out_time "]);
 model =  db.bookm.Where(x=>x.intime>= newintime && x.out_time <= newouttime ).First();
```

If I convert to `string` it works .
I want to insert it as for eg(18:23:44)

Comment: What you need to do insert or query from db?

Comment: Time in HH:MI:SS format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your database is MS SQL Server.

SQL Server stores time in `HH:MI:SS` format. 
Use `TimeSpan` in your model to store/get the data.

Here is another possible solution: [How to save time only without the date using ASP.NET MVC 5 Data Annotation "DataType.Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693572/how-to-save-time-only-without-the-date-using-asp-net-mvc-5-data-annotation-data)

Comment: Actually, SQL Server *Displays* time in `HH:MI:SS`, but it is stored as the number of ticks since midnight, Ticks being 100 nanosecond.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime newintime = DateTime.Parse(Request["intime"].ToLongTimeString()); //change here
DateTime newouttime = DateTime.Parse(Request["out_time"].ToLongTimeString());// here also
model =  db.bookm.Where(x=>x.intime>= newintime && x.out_time <= newouttime ).First();
```

user ToLongTimeString();

Comment: Nop, it wont work . we cannot convert string to system.datetime

Comment: sorry my mistake....DateTime newintime = DateTime.Parse(Request["intime"]).ToLongTimeString();